# Nuxt.js returning 404 on CSS and JS files - is this a cache issue?

Tags: caching, nuxt.js, browser-cache, netlify

I have a statically generated site using Nuxt.js, and it is hosted on Netlify and everything works fine. However, when I run any crawls or page speed tests, I always notice 404s on the public directory, specifically on the nuxt generated JS and CSS files such as `/_nuxt/4cb43ec.modern.js` or `/_nuxt/css/af132ef.css`

Is this a cache problem from

1. The tools running the crawls / speeds tests (browser/crawler cache)
2. Netlify cache, serving an old version to a returning user

I don't mind toomuch about these, but my main concern is if it's effecting any users, and if it's effecting SEO ranking, and I'm curious if there is a way I can remedy this.